# How to auto scroll up li element when the corresponding element is showing using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this HTML page:

https://shibbir.dev/demo-work/html-one-page/

On this page, you will see a second sticky sidebar whose title is **"Credit ipotecar"**

In this sidebar, I have a few **li** elements. If you **click** on any **li** element you will scroll down to the **corresponding div** on the right side.

But the problem is I can see only a few **li** elements on the sidebar thus I can't click on other **li** elements to see another corresponding **div**.

So, how can I make the last **li** element **scroll up** once I click on the last viewable **li** element?

**Something like this example:**

https://discount.ro/cataloage/pepco-ro/cupon-de-reducere-pepco-colectia-de-rochii-din-bumbac-organic-02-15-iunie-2022-16353/#section11

**My JS Code:**

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).scroll(function () {

            var scrollBar = $(this).scrollTop();
            var navigate = document.querySelector(".sh-body-container div").offsetTop
    
            $(".sh-body-container div").each(function (index) {
                var elTop = $(this).offset().top;
                var elHeight = $(this).height();
    
                if (scrollBar >= elTop - navigate && scrollBar < elTop + elHeight) {
                    $(".sh-body-sidebar ul li").eq(index).addClass("sidebarActive").siblings().removeClass("sidebarActive");
                }
            });
        });

        $(".sh-see-more").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var that = $(this);
            that.prev(".sh-see-more-details").toggleClass("is-active");
        });

        $(".hide-show").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var that = $(this);
            var plusSign = that.children("a").text();
            if( "+" == plusSign ) {
                that.children("a").text("-");
            } else {
                that.children("a").text("+");
            }
            var faq = that.next(".sh-faq-answer").toggleClass("faq-active");;
        });

        $(".sh-mobile-calculator-icon").click(function() {
            $(".sh-calculator").addClass("show-calculator");
            $(".show-filter").show();
            $(".show-filter a").click(function() {
                $(".sh-calculator").removeClass("show-calculator");
            });
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: please share your css file too.

Comment: @NayeemM.Muzahid you can find the CSS code here at this URL: https://shibbir.dev/demo-work/html-one-page/style.css