# jQuery get the children distance from parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this HTML:

```js
console.log( $(".sh-sidebar-content").height() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sh-sidebar-content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#one">Compară ofertele noastre pentru a găsi cel mai bun credit ipotecar sau Prima Casă</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Ce este un credit ipotecar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Care sunt condițiile de acordare ale unui credit ipotecar pentru cumpărarea sau construirea unei locuințe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Care este suma maximă pe care o pot împrumuta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#five">Ce este creditul Noua Casă (fost Prima Casă)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#six">Care sunt condițiile de acordare ale unui credit prin Noua Casă</a></li>
    <li><a href="#seven">Care este suma maximă pe care o pot împrumuta prin Noua Casă</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eight">Acte necesare pentru solicitarea unui credit ipotecar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nine">Acte necesare pentru solicitarea unui credit Noua Casă</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ten">Care este procedura de acordare pentru un credit ipotecar?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eleven">Care este procedura de acordare a unui credit Noua Casă?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#twelve">Cum se restituie un credit ipotecar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#thirteen">Cum se restituie un credit obținut prin programul Noua Casă</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Based on this class `sh-sidebar-content` I need to get the distance of each **li** element.

I can get the height of `sh-sidebar-content` class using

```
$(".sh-sidebar-content").height()
```

It shows me the height value based on the window height. For eg: 735.

So, Now, I need to get the distance from this **value** of the **li** element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [position](https://api.jquery.com/position/) for this. Get the base point (div) position, then get each `li`'s position, then subtract.

```js
let divPos = $(".sh-sidebar-content").position();

$(".sh-sidebar-content li").each(function(i)
{
  console.log( $(this).position().top - divPos.top );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sh-sidebar-content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#one">Compară ofertele noastre pentru a găsi cel mai bun credit ipotecar sau Prima Casă</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Ce este un credit ipotecar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Care sunt condițiile de acordare ale unui credit ipotecar pentru cumpărarea sau construirea unei locuințe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Care este suma maximă pe care o pot împrumuta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#five">Ce este creditul Noua Casă (fost Prima Casă)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#six">Care sunt condițiile de acordare ale unui credit prin Noua Casă</a></li>
    <li><a href="#seven">Care este suma maximă pe care o pot împrumuta prin Noua Casă</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eight">Acte necesare pentru solicitarea unui credit ipotecar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nine">Acte necesare pentru solicitarea unui credit Noua Casă</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ten">Care este procedura de acordare pentru un credit ipotecar?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eleven">Care este procedura de acordare a unui credit Noua Casă?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#twelve">Cum se restituie un credit ipotecar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#thirteen">Cum se restituie un credit obținut prin programul Noua Casă</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me try it

Comment: Yes, It's working. Would you please answer me this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72497535/how-to-auto-scroll-up-li-element-when-the-corresponding-element-is-showing-using

Comment: any answer to that question'?

Comment: Still looking for a solution.

Comment: @Shibbir https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245318/shibbir

Comment: can send me again please?